# Can I ship Webassembly or run it as Assemblyscript on client side?

Tags: webassembly

Ok so here goes:
BIT OF BACKGROUND:
I have a vision where browsers (which are the trully cross platform standards of today... and hopefully of tomorrow), are used as a kind of "local server" where you store (indexeddb ... I know its not perfect... but its all we have at the moment) data that is truly owned by the users and is not persisted unless they want to share their data explicitly.

This kind of application running cross platfrom on browsers is not meant to be beat any marathons but with webassembly I thought there might be an opportunity to make some smart improvements in performances.

QUESTION:
For this to happen, I wanted to try out assembly script for the fun of it, does webassembly have ot exist in the server or can it be shipped along with the rest of the application (in a Cordova type fashion) to use the client CPU for optimization?

Appreciate this shows a lack of understanding of it... but Im getting started with it so give me some slack :)
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I ship Webassembly or run it as Assemblyscript on client side?

Yes, WebAssembly was designed first and foremost as a browser-based runtime for client-side applications.

You can write applications in Rust, C#, C++, AssemblyScript, Go, and a great many other languages and run them on the browser without a server (beyond a simple static content server for delivering the HTML / WebAssembly content)